# I try to update gridview using entity framework

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

```
Protected Sub GridView_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
```

```
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    Dim CustomerName As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("CustomerName"), TextBox)
    Dim db As New SampleEntities()
    Dim ID As Integer = GridView.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value
    Dim obj = db.tblCustomer.First(Function(x) x.ID = ID)
    obj.CustomerName = CustomerName.Text
    db.SaveChanges()
    GridView.EditIndex = -1
    BindData()
```

End Sub

`Protected Sub BindData()
      Dim db As New SampleEntities()
      Dim ps = (From p In db.tblCustomer
                  Select p)
        If ps.Count() > 0 Then
            GridView.DataSource = ps.ToList()
            GridView.DataBind()
        Else
            GridView.DataSource = Nothing
            GridView.DataBind()
        End If`

End Sub

i got an error like this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How can i solve it. 
Please help me.

Comment: Where you are getting error?

Comment: Never name controls the same as it's class name,  try naming it gvCustomers.

Comment: obj.CustomerName = CustomerName.Text <== When i update data in column CustomerName that value is nothing

Answer (score 2):

On which line you are getting this error. If you are getting this error at

GridView.DataSource = ps.ToList()

then try    **If ps!=null** then instead of    If ps.Count() > 0 Then.

Comment: I think the problem is i can't get new data form gridview 'Custommer.text' is null value that  error in line  obj.CustomerName = CustomerName.Text

Comment: Yes, your datasource is null thats why you are getting this problem.